# Is there a python function that can convert an image into a set of image 'windows'?

Tags: python, neural-network, computer-vision

I am training a Convolutional Neural Network (in tensorflow-gpu) to segment histology slides.

My problem is that the prediction method is extremely slow. The architecture of the neural network is set-up to receive a 75 x 75 RGB pixel array as an input, and classify **the central pixel**. In other words, for each 75x75 window of pixels the neural net receives, it only classifies 1 pixel (**at the window's centre**):

I've set up the neural network in this way so that it can be scaled-up and applied to any size image. Each 'window' exists purely to contextualise it's central pixel, which the neural network classifies. The prediction method loops through every pixel in the input image and uses its corresponding 75 x 75 RGB window to classify it.

My current method of generating the 75x75 windows is python-written, slow and unnecessarily serialised (uses for-loops).

**Does a parallelised method, that can convert an image into a set of RGB windows, exist?**

For example, it would convert a 400 x 700 x 3 image into an matrix of size 280'000 x 75 x 75 x 3. This is because as there are 280'000 pixels in the input image (400x700=280'000), and therefore there should be 280'000 windows, with each of the input's pixels at their centre. As each window has the dimension 75 x 75 x 3, and there are 280'000 windows, the method's output size would be 280'000 x 75 x 75 x 3.

Ideally, I imagine such a method would utilise any available GPUs, due to their advantages in image-processing and parallelised jobs.

Thank you for reading, all suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem could help you get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @SimónRamírezAmaya I've actually managed to find a solution online, so I'll post it as an answer now:)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the perfect function, [skimage.util.view_as_windows()](https://kite.com/python/docs/skimage.util.view_as_windows).
Here is how I used this function, in an example:

First open the image and set your preferred 'window' size:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as windows
    
#lets use a window size of 75 pixels
window_size=75
#load image
data = np.asarray(Image.open("N:\\Insigneo Research Project\\MyScripts\\PoC_CNN\\MATLABLabelling\\split image\\12-1550A-001_01_01.png"))
print(data.shape)

img = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

Output: (742, 486, 3), (Image in link below)
```

[Output of above cell: A loaded example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNGp.png)

Then, you must use the window size [to pad](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) each of the RGB channels, to allow all pixels to have their own centralised window (padding allows the edge pixels to be centralised):

```
#assertion ensures window dimensions are odd, ensuring a 'central' pixel exists.
assert window_size%2==1
buffer = int((window_size-1)/2)

padded_image_data = [0]*3
for i in range(3):
    padded_image_data[i] = np.pad(data[:,:,i], (buffer,buffer), 'symmetric')
padded_image_data = np.dstack((padded_image_data[0],padded_image_data[1],padded_image_data[2]))

img = plt.imshow(padded_image_data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

Output: (Image in link below)
```

[Output image of above cell: Symmetrically padded version of example image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOkku.jpg)

And then finally, apply the view_as_windows (shortened to 'windows') function to the padded RGB image:

```
large_window_matrix = windows(padded_image_data, ((window_size,window_size,3))).reshape(data.shape[0]*data.shape[1],window_size,window_size,3)
print(large_window_matrix.shape)

img = plt.imshow(large_window_matrix[1], interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

Output: (360612, 75, 75, 3), (Image in link below)
```

[Output of above cell: The first 75x75 RGB window from the padded example image. This window is centred around the most upper-left pixel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXXhK.png)

There you have it! the 'large_window_matrix' corresponds to the large matrix holding all the RGB windows:)